# Compilation issue with boost range copy of filesystem path

Tags: boost, boost-filesystem, boost-range

The following code fails to compile with 1.58 while it was compiling with 1.46. I guess it's a type conversion issue, but I can't make it right.

**my code**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost;
using namespace filesystem;
using namespace adaptors;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    recursive_directory_iterator beg = recursive_directory_iterator(".");
    recursive_directory_iterator end = recursive_directory_iterator();

    iterator_range<recursive_directory_iterator> files = 
        make_iterator_range(beg, end);

    std::function<bool (path const & path)> fileFilter = 
        [](path const & path) -> bool {
        return is_regular_file(path);
    };

    std::vector<path> paths;
    copy(files | filtered(fileFilter), std::back_inserter(paths));

    // works:
    //copy(files, std::back_inserter(paths));

    // also works:
    //for(recursive_directory_iterator it = beg; it != end; ++it){
    //    if(fileFilter(*it)){
    //        paths.push_back(*it);
    //    }
    //}
}
```

**Error message (VS2010)**

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::recursive_directory_iterator(const
>   boost::filesystem::path
>   &,boost::filesystem::symlink_option::enum_type)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from
>   'boost::iterators::detail::postfix_increment_proxy' to
>   'const boost::filesystem::path
>   &'    [...]\boost\1.58.0_32\include\boost-1_58\boost\range\concepts.hpp   201 1   [...]

Can anyone help ?

**Edit**

Filed as https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11228.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug introduced somewhere since Boost 1.55. Using boost 1.55 this compiles ok.

It could be this bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10989

> boost_1_57_0/boost/concept_check.hpp|210 col 13| error: conversion from ‘boost::iterators::single_pass_traversal_tag’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag’ requested

The `filtered` adaptor requires the input to be `forward_traversal` tag. But `recursive_directory_iterator` only promises `single_pass_traversal` tag:

```
        BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT((
            Convertible<
                BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME ForwardIteratorConcept::traversal_category,
                forward_traversal_tag
            >));
```

### WORKAROUND

You can disable concept checks for now: `-DBOOST_RANGE_ENABLE_CONCEPT_ASSERT=0`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44b367ed57ea077c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using namespace boost::adaptors;

int main() {
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator beg("."), end;

    auto fileFilter = [](fs::path const & path) { return is_regular_file(path); };

    std::vector<fs::path> paths;
    copy(boost::make_iterator_range(beg, end) | filtered(fileFilter), std::back_inserter(paths));

    for(auto& p : paths)
        std::cout << p << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
"./main.cpp"
"./a.out"
```

Comment: I tried the 10989 bug fix, but that didn't make it. I filed a new bug. In the meantime, your workaround works fine. Thanks!